# How do a loop n.times in Liquid templating using an existing for loop

Tags: loops, liquid

In ruby I can do n.times do, is it possible to do this in Liquid markup?

My current loop is: for video in site.posts my goal is to run this loop 2 times.  There are currently 4 objects that will be called through the loop but I want 8.  I hope this is clear!

Answer (score 23):

You should be able to use a for loop with a range (`n` is the number of iterations):

```
{% for num in (1..n) %}
```

In some instances of Shopify Liquid, it may also work to use

```
{% for num in (1...n) %}
```

Comment: my current loop: for video in site.posts, so I would convert this to: for video in site posts (1...n)?

Comment: @TJSherrill, your comment changes the problem. Please update the question. The answer to your new question is: `{% for video in site.posts limit: n %}`.

Comment: thanks and I edited the question.  Adding limit: n simply limits the number it items the loop can find, it doesn't force the loop to completely iterate twice (n).

Comment: Note that the "strict" syntax uses two dots: `{% for num in (1..n) %}`.  You can use three dots in "lax" mode (which is the default).

Answer (score 3):

If like me you want to have a dynamic number that is not based upon a collection length or in-build var you can use includes and default values with capture to work wonders

```
{% capture count %}{{include.count|default:16}}{% endcapture %}
{% for num in (1...count) %}
    {{num}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to the game here, but for anyone who is confused about this, here is what you can do.

You take what the other answers have said:

```
{% for num in (1..n) %}
```

And you wrap that around your other forloop. In the original request for video in site.post looping 2 times, it would loop like this

```
{% for i in (1..2) %}
  {% for video in site.posts %}
    Do your loop stuff here
  {% endloop %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now you're controlling the number of times your original loop will iterate through its total set